# Python replace string in text file with value from list

Tags: python, string, replace

My problem is to replace strings in a text file, with another string.  These key strings are in a list called word_list.  I've tried the following, nothing seems to work.  It prints out the sentence in document.text as it appears, with no replacement:

```
  word_list = {'hi' : 'test', 'how' : 'teddy'} 

  with open("document.txt") as main:
      words = main.read().split()

   replaced = []
   for y in words:
         replacement = word_list.get(y, y)
         replaced.append(replacement)
   text = ' '.join(word_list.get(y, y) for y in words)


   print text

   new_main = open("done.txt", 'w')
   new_main.write(text)
   new_main.close()
```

Content of document.txt:

```
   hi you, how is he?
```

Current output is the same as document.txt when it should be:

```
   test you, teddy is he?
```

Any solutions/ help would be appreciated :)

Comment: why do you want to go through all of this when you can use `replace`  method

Comment: `word_list` is, despite its name, a dictionary... Also, you completely ignore `replaced` when you create the `text` at the end, preferring instead to use a generator expression.

Comment: and your code works for me ?

Comment: "It prints out the sentence in document.text" -> you did check the done.txt file right?

Comment: Your code works fine. what is your problem?

Comment: @grc yes I did, and the same sentence which is printed, and that in test is saved to done.txt.

Comment: @SakibAhammed it does not do anything for me, other than print the exact same sentence in document.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
word_list = {'hi' : 'test', 'how' : 'teddy'} 

with open("document.txt") as main:
    with open('done.txt', 'w') as new_main:
        input_data = main.read()
        for key, value in word_list.iteritems():
            input_data = input_data.replace(key, value)

        new_main.write(input_data)
```

This will read the entire contents of the file (not the most efficient if it's a large file), then iterate over your search and replace items in your dictionary, and call replace on the input text. Once complete it will write the data out to your new file.

Some things to remember with this approach

- if your input file is large, it will be slow
- you search pattern can also match word fragments, ie. `hi` will watch `which`, so you should cater for that too.

Comment: I know, which is why I was editing it to include some caveats of the naive approach.

Comment: @ChristianWitts your solution work, thanks :) however,if I wanted to avoid replacing word fragments of other strings, how would this be done?

Comment: @user47467 By using a regular expression with `\b` for "word boundary", as in panda's answer, but I'd suggest using a different regex... see comments.

Answer (score 2):

As you seem to want to replace words, this will use a more natural definition of 'word':

```
import re
word_list = {'hi' : 'test', 'how' : 'teddy'}
with open('document.txt') as main, open('done.txt', 'w') as done:
    text = main.read()
    done.write(re.sub(r'\b\w+\b', lambda x: word_list.get(x.group(), x.group()), text))
```

Comment: Better use `r"\b(" + "|".join(word_list) + r")\b",` as pattern, so you don't needlessly replace _every_ word. Also, `\w` would not work if those words contain unusual characters.

Comment: @tobias_k, testing each word for N variants is O(N) while needlessly replacing it is O(1) (though likely a longer operation). Where the balance lies is a matter of profiling. And \w is by definition a word symbol.

Comment: If you have N alternatives, each has to be checked until the correct one is found, there's nothing else the regexp engine could do.

Comment: python set is no different from dict, both are O(1) average

Comment: @tobias_k, I tested it on a meagre 10000 words dictionary, and sure enough, the joined regexp sub operation runs 425 times slower

Comment: Certainly depends on the number of words in the dictionary, the length of the text and the density of those words in the text. My results were different, but whatever...